# Program won't loop or add to a list

Tags: python, levels, reward-system

I have made (or more, I'm trying to make) a program to help me calculate some figures.
I have some levels that each give a reward and to give out the rewards I prefer to not insert each amount and add them all up to get the totals.

I've made it so that I write the level number, it adds the amount to a list, it loops again, I insert a different number etc.

But it doesn't loop **or** add the numbers to the list.

Heres my super un-compact code:

```py
lists = []
total = 0
def moneyz():
    level=input('-> ')
    print('g') #just a testing bookmark
    print(level) #same here
    if level==1:
        print('oo') #and here
        lists.apped('150')
        total==total+150

    elif level == 2:
        lists.apped('225')
        total==total+225
        moneyz()

    elif level == 3:
        lists.apped('330')
        total==total+330
        moneyz()

    elif level == 4:
        lists.apped('500')
        total==total+500
        moneyz()

    elif level == 5:
        lists.apped('1000')
        total==total+1000
        moneyz()

    elif level == 6:
        lists.apped('1500')
        total==total+1500
        moneyz()

    elif level == 7:
        lists.apped('2250')
        total==total+2250
        moneyz()

    elif level == 8:
        lists.apped('3400')
        total==total+3400
        moneyz()

    elif level == 9:
        lists.apped('5000')
        total==total+5000
        moneyz()

    elif level == 10:
        lists.apped('15000')
        total==total+15000
        moneyz()


moneyz()
print(lists)
print(total)
```

Comment: Lists have an `append` method, not `apped`. But your code as it is would throw errors, in which case the error traceback should be included in the question. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: While that might help me, it doesnt help the actual problem of it not looping. Thanks for the question formatting help.

Comment: The errors that the code is producing will help tell you why it's not looping.  Looking at the errors that your code throws is an important part of learning how to fix it, which is why you should include those errors as part of asking other people for help.

Comment: It's not giving any errors its just giving me this:
`-> 1
g
1
[]
0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see three bugs in this code:

1. `level` is a `str`, so it will never equal an `int`.  None of your `if` checks will ever be satisfied, which is why your function isn't recursing.  A way to spot this in debugging would have been to add a `print(repr(level))` after you receive the input; you'd see that it's a value like `'1'` (a string) instead of `1` (an integer).
2. There is no such thing as `apped()`, so once you hit that line of code (which currently isn't happening because your `if` checks never match), it'd raise an `AttributeError`.
3. Your `total` is never going to increase because you're using the `==` (equality check) operator rather than the `=` (assignment) operator.

Here's a much shorter (working) version of the program, using a simple lookup table in place of a bunch of `if` statements:

```
# Rewards for levels 0 to 10.
rewards = [0, 150, 225, 330, 500, 1000, 1500, 2250, 3400, 5000, 15000]

# Running totals.
lists = []
total = 0

while True:
    # Get reward level from the user.  If not a valid reward level, stop.
    level = input('-> ')
    try:
        level_num = int(level)
    except ValueError:
        break
    if level_num not in range(len(rewards)):
        break

    # Add the reward to the lists and the total.
    reward = rewards[level_num]
    lists.append(reward)
    total += reward

# Final output.
print(lists)
print(total)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! And thanks for rewriting the code and making it compact for me! Thanks a lot!
The `apped` was my error...

Answer (score 0):

You are using `level==1`where level is a string as `input()` returns a string and you are comparing it with int.

You should try `level=='1'` or convert level to int by `level = int(input("->"))`.

Also, list has `append()` method and not `apped()`

Also, `total==total+1000` won't help for adding. It will just check if value of total is equal to total plus 1000. You should use `total = total + 1000` for adding value.

Here is one sample modified if block:

```
if level=='1':
        print('oo') #and here
        lists.append('150')
        total=total+150
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. The `apped` was just me being stupid and forgetting to add an `n`. The code works now!